# Connectedness of a hyperbola to the x-axis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, connectedness

Given my definition of connected as:
M is connected if it contains no proper clopen subsets.

And the set H as {(x,y) : xy = 1 and x,y>0 }, with the set X representing the x-axis, is the set S = X U H connected?

My initial thought is no, as using the open ball definition of:

For all p in M, there is an r such that Mr(p) contains only points in M, you can set r = 1/2y and trivially show this.

But, I feel that there's something I'm missing here. I know that the topologist's sine curve is a connected set to the Y axis, and they seem eerily similar. So, am I missing something?

Comment: A space $ X$ is connected iff it contains no proper NON-EMPTY clopen subsets.Equivalently , whenever  $A,B$ are open  and disjoint in $X$,and $X=A\cup B$ then at least one of $A,B$ is empty

Answer (score 5):

Define a function $f:S \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ by $f(x,y) = xy$ This is continuous (why?)

$\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are both open and closed subusets of $\{0,1\}$. $f^{-1}(0) = X$ and $f^{-1}(1) = H$. So $H$ and $X$ are proper open and closed subsets of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us show that the set $X$ is both open and closed in the set $S$ with subspace topology gotten from $\mathbb{R}^2$. $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y)=xy$ is continuous as it is restriction of the continuous map (polynomial ) from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Now $f^{-1}(0)=X$ so $X$ is closed and it is open since the complement is also closed being $f^{-1}(1)$.

Comment: The sine curve situation is different as there are limit points of $sin(1/x)$ on the $Y$ axis so there is no way to separate the set.